# Determinants of transformations

Tags: linear-transformations

Provided a linear transformation $G: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$, given by $G(v) = 2v$. Since $G$ is a composite of scaling by a factor of $2$ and the identity map has determinant $1$, then $\det(G) = 2$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3):

You're wrong: the determinant is linear w.r.t. *each* row (or column) of a matrix, so in dimension $3$,
$$\det(2I)=2^3\det I=8.$$

Comment: Could you further explain that? I thought the determinant of an identity matrix is 1

Comment: It indeed is $1$. But when you multiply  a matrix by a scalar $\lambda$, each coefficient, hence each row ot column, is multiplied by this scalar, so that, by multilinearity, the determinant is multiplied by $\lambda^n$, where $n\times n$ is the dimension of the matrix.